# Upload fails with no description

Tags: teamcity, phrase

I have set access_token & project_id variables for phrase but when trying to push i get
`Uploading locales/en-default.json... failed to create locale: 404 Not Found` in TeamCity.
Not sure if unable to find the project (but all tokens and ids are fresh) or something wrong with phrase